# cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery vs cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery performance

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I have more than a billion records in collection, I would like to know the performance of the `cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery` and `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery`.

I need to query this much data very frequently, so please suggest which type of query is good for my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your query is specifying a value, use the query construct for a value. Don’t overthink it.

The one exception is if you’re passing a lot of values with one OR query. Then you should test if with your dataset doing an OR of many value queries or a range query with a list does better.

Comment: Other considerations are whether you are expecting to query with a somewhat controlled set of values, or if it's going to be pseudo-random or up to billions of values and the volume of requests. Value queries will cache the term list hits, so repeated queries for the same value will usually be snappy, but if you are querying with tons of unique values, you could cause some churn for the term list cache and fill it with junk, and may find that range-query is better. In general, either will work just fine, but under heavy loads and extreme cases, you should performance test and compare.